# Accessing scm site fail after authenticating with Azure AD on an ILB ASE with custom domain

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, kudu, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have setup ILB ASE v2, using the appserviceenvironment.net. I want to manage azure function using azure portal. My organization does not allow the use of azure portal from anywhere but out office network, and I can't use site to site VPN.

We know the best practice is to manage ASE within the vNET but I want to expose the SCM site through app gateway.

Problem 1: I can't access the site over internet because I'm using appserviveenvironment

Added a custom domain name xyz.net, got two different wildcard cert one for *.xyz.net and a second one for *.scm.xyz.net
Note: SAN certificate can't be used on my org.

Configure app gateway with 2 multisite listeners, one MyApp.xyz.net and myapp.scm.xyz.net with the proper certificate on each listener.

Added an https setting for https myapp.scm.xyz.net to overwrite the host header with the myapp.scm.ase-01.appserviceenvironment.net

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://sre-paas.appserviceenvironment.net/&client_id=ccda0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787ab&resource=https://management.core.windows.net/&scope=user_impersonation openid&nonce=ed93cd1b-3456-4b45-08d7-1e2a3820cd9a&site_id=500989&response_mode=form_post&state=https://prov-baas.scm.sre-paas.appserviceenvironment.net/

The request goes through the gateway to ILB ASE, my browser redirect to azure ad, azure ad authenticate me but it redirect back to redirect_uri.

Question:

How can I set the redirect uri?, this value is coming from SCM site.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm using the kudu basicauth endpoint to authenticate then I can simple access the SCM site through the gateway, it will be better if we can integrate with OIDC.